# Change Xamarin Forms Status Bar Color to Gradient for iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, statusbar

I was looking for this solution since yesterday on how to change the color of status bar (only) for iOS device globally.

In android I just do it like this:

```
var window = Window;
window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
window.SetBackgroundDrawable(GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient));
```

but I cannot find a way like this in iOS.

Please help. thanks

Comment: You can refer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980367/xamarin-forms-ios-hamburger-menu-header-color-differs-from-status-bar/49981197#49981197

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this
  UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
    if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
    {
        statusBar.BackgroundColor = color.ToUIColor();
    }
In my case color is passed as argument and is of type Xamarin.Forms.Color.

In addition you might want to set style of status bar across all pages, depending on your needs.

<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
```

Comment: In app delegate on finish launching method and that key and value in info plist